# How can I dynamically set new data in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using [Gantt chart](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart) to create a data visualization. I am getting some data from ElasticSearch on incremental basis and I need to assign the new data to the chart. How can I achieve this?

Here is a [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/20kt84vo/7/) to look in.

Data format which needs to be added dynamically

```
[{
    "name": "login-util-sample",
    "pointRange": 0,
    "borderRadius": 1,
    "pointWidth": 15,
    "data": [{
        "x": 1451865600000,
        "x2": 1451865600000,
        "y": 0,
        "total_seconds": -1451865600000
    }, {
        "x": 1451952000000,
        "x2": 1451952000000,
        "y": 0,
        "total_seconds": -1451952000000
    }]
}, {
    "name": "SfdcObmReceiverCloudSvc",
    "pointRange": 0,
    "borderRadius": 1,
    "pointWidth": 15,
    "data": [{
        "x": 1451865600000,
        "x2": 1451865600000,
        "y": 1,
        "total_seconds": -1451865600000
    }, {
        "x": 1451952000000,
        "x2": 1451952000000,
        "y": 1,
        "total_seconds": -1451952000000
    }]
}, {
    "name": "create-update-aff-cloud",
    "pointRange": 0,
    "borderRadius": 1,
    "pointWidth": 15,
    "data": [{
        "x": 1451865600000,
        "x2": 1451865602000,
        "y": 3,
        "total_seconds": -1451865598000
    }, {
        "x": 1451952000000,
        "x2": 1451952017000,
        "y": 3,
        "total_seconds": -1451951983000
    }]
}]
```

Chart option

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'xrange',
        renderTo: 'chart',
        height: 600,
        zoomType: 'xy',
        resetZoomButton: {
            theme: {
                fill: 'white',
                stroke: 'silver',
                r: 0,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fill: '#41739D',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        events: {
            load: function(e) {
                var max = maxDate;
                var range = (24 * 3600 * 1000) * 7; // one day * 7
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(max - range, max);
                //resetMin = (max - range);
                //resetMax = max;
            },
            selection: function(event) {
                if (event.xAxis) {
                    console.log('min: ' + event.xAxis[0].min + ', max: ' + event.xAxis[0].max);
                } else {
                    console.log('Selection reset');
                    this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(resetMin, resetMax);
                    is1stZoom = true;
                    console.log('Reset to min: ' + resetMin + ', max: ' + resetMax);
                }
            },
            redraw: function() {
                var chart = this,
                    each = Highcharts.each;

                each(chart.series, function(s, i) {
                    each(s.points, function(p, j) {
                        if (p.graphic) {
                            p.graphic.css({
                                'stroke-width': 1,
                                'stroke': p.color
                            })
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Processes Run'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: xAxisStepping,
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            month: '%b %e, %Y'
        },
        min: minDate,
        max: maxDate,
        minRange: 1000,
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                if (is1stZoom) {
                    resetMin = e.min;
                    resetMax = e.max;
                    is1stZoom = false;
                    console.log('Should get reset to min: ' + e.min + ', max: ' + e.max);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickInterval: 1,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: '',
        categories: categories,
        min: minY,
        max: maxY,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: true,
        margin: 2
    },
    series: data,
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var seriesName = this.series.name;
            return seriesName;
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            animation: false,
            turboThreshold: 100000000,
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on button click I doing something like below, which says `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
        chart.series[i].setData(item);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the click handler as follows:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
  for (var i=0;i<newData.length;i++) {                      
    chart.highcharts().addSeries(newData[i], true);
  };
});
```

The object that is returned when using the jQuery-Style initializer is just a jQuery-Object of the DOM-Element where the chart is inserted. To get the Highcharts-Object representing that chart you have to call `highcharts` on that object again.

See my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/20kt84vo/9/

Alternatively you could replace the jQuery-Style initializer with the alternative syntax `var chart = new Highcharts.chart` where you have to provide the containing DOM-Element in the `renderTo` config option.

See http://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/da2cvc5j/

Comment: In my actual application I am using `chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(values);` so I just used `chart.addSeries(values[i], true);` which solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but there is a problem with `addSeries` it adds multiple instances of itself on button click, but instead I want to replace the old value with new one every time I get a new response or in this case a button click (for same `newData`).

Comment: you have to do that manually: give your series an attribute `id` with a unique identifier. Then in the onclick you have to check if the chart already contains that series (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get). If not, add it as usual. If it contains that series: get the series from the chart and update the Data of that series.